# Rewrite rule in .htaccess that blocks all connections with specific Query String value

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried a few variations, but can anyone help me out with a rewrite rule in a .htaccess that would block all connections where a query string value of `x=y`.

```
/app/index.php?x=y
```

Answer (score 0):

To match the query string you need to use a condition that checks the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only.

So, to block (403 Forbidden) any request that contains a query string of `x=y` with mod_rewrite, you would do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^x=y$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The regex `^` matches *anything*. The hyphen (`-`) in the *substitution* is a placeholder for *no* substitution.